# How to assign javascript variable to last character of a string

Tags: automated-testing, javascript

Hello I am trying to implement automated test scripts using NewRelic.  I am engineering javascript such that I print the last character of a field on the page that is always 8 characters.  I have this:

```
var last_character=page_value.charAt(8);
console.log('test last_character='+last_character)
```

but it only prints 'test last_character='!  Is this a javascript variable scoping issue?  I have never understood that!

Comment: There is a discrepancy between your nick (user name) and your skill level :-)

Comment: This is a really basic question: javascript starts counting the index at *0* not 1. So you need `charAt(7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `.charAt(7)` since js starts indexing at position 0.

Comment: Thank you!  This was the problem.  I wish javascript gave an error rather than an un-usable value!

Comment: @SrGuy Since you know it's an 8 character string, you can do this. You may want to do str.charAt(str.length - 1) in the future in case the string changes on you.

Comment: string.slice(-1) is a better approach, since it is cross-browser.